# Navigation voice not loud enough

Tags: navigation, volume

I have a Galaxy S and I love using my navigation app. The problem is she isn't loud enough. I think I have the speaker turned all the way up. Is there way to make it louder? It's a straight talk if that matters.

Comment: I often find the navigation voice isn't loud enough on my Galaxy Nexus, so I don't think it's specific to your device.

Comment: She? I'm pretty sure mine's a "he"!?

Answer (score 1):

There are sevelar volume booster available on the Google Playstore, as e.g. [Speaker Boost](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.omegacentauri.SpeakerBoost) or [Volume Booster](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.liquidsoft.entertainment.volume.booster) (for more alternatives, try [this search](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=volume+booster&c=apps)). You might want to give one of them a try.